# Implementing NTLM silent login with Java

Tags: ntlmv2

Hoping someone can remedy my naivety when it comes to calling a simple URL to an application (which returns XML) using NTLMv2.

I have read pretty much every question and page there is but I am left with one overriding curiosity. I am using the HTTPClient at present (although this can be changed) along with the latest JDK (at the time of writing).

Here is an example page which appears to call the JCIFS library:
http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/ntlm.html

All looks good, albeit confusing, but this highlights the question that many of the examples I have seen raises - the issue of supplying NTCredentials.

To me the whole point of NTLM is so that I do not have to supply credentials. The target aplication is set up to use NTLM so surely the user credntials of the currently logged in user should be used? Why should I be supplying any credentials myself?

Apologies if I am missing something obvious here. I just need the most basic for of NTLM SSO possible using Java. I don't care what version of what, I am able to use the latest of anything.

Holding out hope! Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's way to do single sign-on in a pure Java environment.

NTLM isn't a solution to single sign-on directly.  NTLM is a challenge/response authentication mechanism and it requires the NTLM hash of the user's password.  Windows machines are able to provide single sign-on using NTLM because the NTLM hash is persisted.  They are then able to compute the response to a challenge based on the persisted hash.

Without access to that hash (and, to my knowledge, you can't simply request it) you need to compute it yourself.  And that requires having the user's password.

Similarly, you can do single sign-on with a Kerberos ticket using SPNEGO authentication (if the remote system is setup to support it, of course) but Java unfortunately reimplemented Kerberos instead of using the system Kerberos libraries.  So even if you were already logged in to the domain, you'd need to go get another Kerberos ticket for Java.  And that means typing your password in again.

The only realistic way to avoid typing in a password to authenticate is to call the native methods.  On Windows, this is [SSPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which will provide you the ability to respond to an NTLM or SPNEGO challenge.  On non-Windows platforms, this is handled by the very similar [GSSAPI](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-current/doc/appdev/gssapi.html) and provides the ability to respond to SPNEGO (Kerberos).